# Match query in Mongoose for arrays does not work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Below you can find my code where I try to exclude from result all users who have authorized user in any of following lists: friends, sentFriendRequests and receiveFriendRequests. Unfortunately the code is not working (other conditions work perfect e.g. filter by id, fullName and email), but I can not figure out why. Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

```
User.findOne({_id: req.user.id})
  .exec(function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      logger.error('Friend 500 ' + err)
      return res.status(500).json({
        code: config.errorCode.status500.code,
        message: config.errorCode.status500.message
      })
    }
    console.log('User id: ' + user._id)
    User.aggregate([
      {
        $project: {
          fullName: {
            $concat: ['$firstName', ' ', '$lastName']
          },
          email: 1,
          avatarPath: 1,
          mutualFriends: {
            $size: {
              $setIntersection: [user.friends, '$friends']
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $match: {
          $and: [
            {
              _id: { $ne: user._id }
            },
            {
              $or: [

                {
                  fullName: { $regex: req.query.keyWord, $options: 'i'}
                },
                {
                  email: { $regex: req.query.keyWord, $options: 'i'}
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              friends: { $ne: user._id }
            },
            {
              receivedFriendRequests: { $ne: user._id }
            },
            {
              sentFriendRequests: { $ne: user._id }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      { $sort: { mutualFriends: -1} }
    ])
      .exec(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          logger.error('Friend 500 ' + err)
          return res.status(500).json({
            code: config.errorCode.status500.code,
            message: config.errorCode.status500.message
          })
        }

        return res.json({
          data: result
        })
      })
  })
```

**Schema Definition**

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String
  },
  frstNameNormalized: {
    type: String
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String
  },
  lastNameNormalized: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    // unique: true,
    // required: true,
    lowercase: true,
  // match: [/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/, 'Please enter a valid email address']
  },
  birthDate: {
    type: Date
  },
  facebookID: {
    type: String
  },
  twitterID: {
    type: String
  },
  password: {
    type: String
  },
  nickname: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  avatarPath: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  friends: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  receivedFriendRequests: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  sentFriendRequests: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  sharedFriendCheckIns: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  resetPasswordToken: String,
  resetPasswordExpires: Date,
  emailConfirmToken: String,
  emailConfirmExpires: Date,
  emailConfirmed: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
})
....
var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

A full model description can be found on the following [link](https://codepaste.net/2ogpjm#). MongoDB version is v3.2.8

Comment: Can you update your question to show the `User` model's schema definition and what your MongoDB server version is? I strongly believe the above query can be done within a single aggregate pipeline that uses `$lookup`, `$redact` or `$filter` operators, just need confirmation on the above.

Comment: Hi, I have added information that you asked from me.

Answer (score 1):

In case that someone needs it, I have resolved this problem. Since I am a beginner the solution is trivial and probably not optimal but it does what it should to.

```
FriendController.route('/find')
.get(passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), function (req, res) {

// get users who are not firends of authorized user nor he/she send to them friend request or received it

var parts = (req.query.keyWord).split(' ')
var firstName = ''
var lastName = ''

if (parts.length > 1) {

  firstName = (req.query.keyWord).split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ')
  lastName = (req.query.keyWord).split(' ').slice(-1).join(' ')

} else {

  firstName = req.query.keyWord
  lastName = req.query.keyWord

}

User.findOne({_id: req.user.id})
  .exec(function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      logger.error('Friend 500 ' + err)
      return res.status(500).json({
        code: config.errorCode.status500.code,
        message: config.errorCode.status500.message
      })
    }

    User.find({
      _id: { $ne: user.id },
      friends: { $ne: user.id },
      receivedFriendRequests: { $ne: user.id },
      sentFriendRequests: { $ne: user.id },
      $or: [
        {
          firstName: { $regex: firstName, $options: 'i'}
        },
        {
          lastName: { $regex: lastName, $options: 'i'}
        },
        {
          email: req.query.keyWord
        }
      ]

    })
      .select('_id')
      .exec(function (err, potentialFriends) {
        if (err) {
          logger.error('Friend 500 ' + err)
          return res.status(500).json({
            code: config.errorCode.status500.code,
            message: config.errorCode.status500.message
          })
        }

        var ids = potentialFriends.map(function (potentialFriend) {
          return potentialFriend._id
        })

        User.aggregate([
          {
            $project: {
              firstName: 1,
              lastName: 1,
              email: 1,
              avatarPath: 1,
              mutualFriends: {
                $size: {
                  $setIntersection: [user.friends, '$friends']
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $match: {
              _id: { $in: ids }
            }

          },
          { $sort: { mutualFriends: -1} }
        ])
          .exec(function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
              logger.error('Friend 500 ' + err)
              return res.status(500).json({
                code: config.errorCode.status500.code,
                message: config.errorCode.status500.message
              })
            }
            return res.json({
              data: result
            })
          })
      })
  })
})
```